# Laravel 4.2 : How to use whereIn() and with() to get a list of items in a one-to-many relationship?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, one-to-many

I want to try to display messages according to their conversation ID. The rules are **a conversation hasMany messages** and **a message belongsTo only one conversation.**

**What I've tried**

I have this in my controller :

```
public function index()
    {
        $from = Input::get('from',null); //timestamp of latest message
        $conv_id = Input::get('conv_id'); //get an array of conversation ids

        $allmessages = Conversations::whereIn('id',$conv_id)->with('messages');
        if(is_null($from)){
           $messages = $allmessages->orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(10);
        }else{
           $messages = $allmessages->where('created_at','>',$from);
        }
        return $messages->get()->reverse();
    }
```

but I got the error message,

```
"SQLSTATE[42S22]:Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'messages.conversations_id' in 
'where clause'(SQL: select * from `messages` where `messages`.`conversations_id` in (1, 2))",
```

I can't seem to figure out where I've gone wrong. Improvement of code will be a bonus. Thank you!

---

I have two models, Conversations and Messages. These are the tables. I intentionally left out the timestamp columns of both tables for this question's purpose.

**Conversations**

```
+---------+----------+
|      id | name     |
+---------+----------+
|       1 |     haha |
|       2 |     hehe |
+---------+----------+
```

**Messages**

```
+---------+----------+-----------------+
| user_id | conv_id  |body             |
+---------+----------+-----------------+
|       1 |     1    |user1 says hi!   |
|       2 |     1    |user2 says seen! |
+---------+----------+-----------------+
```

Here is the function linking those two models.

**Conversation model**

```
public function messages(){
        return $this->hasMany('Messages');
    }
```

**Messages model**

```
 public function conversations(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Conversations');
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error message says

> messages.conversations_id

But your table schema is listed as

> conv_id

So it seems you are using the wrong id field somewhere (I cant tell where as you have not posted enough code - but you should be able to find it. If not - post more code from your model).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the relation in your Messages model to:

```
public function conversations() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Conversations', 'conv_id');
}
```

The second parameter specifies the column to use as the foreign key: by default it would be 'conversations_id' (based on the model name).